# Encoding audio files then renaming them with a bash script

Tags: bash, audio, wav

I'm writing a Bash script that will run on Linux to convert/encode audio files

The conversion works fine so far, but when it comes to renaming the produced files according to a specific pattern that I have to stick with it produces errors.

A file with the name Audio-001.flac has to be renamed to 
2552011-Unit05-Fil001.flac following the pattern: [Recording Date-Recording Unit ID-File ID]

The code I'm using for rename:

`echo "Enter Recording Date, Recording Unit-ID, and File-ID Separated by SPACE"`

`read RD RU FID`

`echo "Your input is: $RD, $RU, $FD " >> /home/user-name/Music/User-Input.txt #This is for logging`

`mv $FLACS/*.flac $FLACS/${RD}-${RU}-${FID}.$flac`

I'm getting an error: `mv: target 22112011-Unit05-File0. is not a directory`

Can I use find and sed?

`find bar -iname "*.wav" -printf 'mv %p %p\n' \`

```
   | sed 's/*\.wav$/${RD}-${RU}-${FID}\.flac/' \
   | while read l; do eval $l; done`
```

Comment: Well, I know I can Use something like [for f in *.wav
do 
flac "$f" -o "${f%.wav}.flac"
done]  I'm just confused how to go about the parsing and renaming mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Nice breakdown of needed work, so:

> 1 - Parse a folder tree (full of .WAV files)

This can be done with several ways, form:

```
find WHERE -print | grep -i PATTERN #or
find WHERE -name ... print0 | xargs -0 -I% ....  #or the simple
echo ./**/*.wav
```

> 2 - use an open source tool such as flac and ffmpeg
>   to convert all the .WAV files in that folder tree to .FLAC

Yes, youre right. The general syntax is

```
flac [<general-options>] [<format-options>] [<encoding options>] [inputfile [...]]
```

> 3- Place the .FLAC files in a newly
>   created folder tree that is identical
>   to the original

Not a hard task. In Linux you can make a directory with the `mkdir` command. You can get the identical tree from the find command (1). Probably will need to use the `dirname` command too. (here is other ways too, but dirname is nice)

> 4- when naming the new .FLAC and their
>   respective folders it will add a
>   unique identifier to the file names
>   i.e folder named 2582001 contains the
>   files 2582001-1.wav and 2582001-2.wav
>   will be recreated and will contain two
>   .FLAC files with the names
>   2582001-REC05-FIL1.FLAC and
>   2582001-REC05-FIL2.FLAC. This
>   structure of the new file names is
>   [Recording Date - Recording Unit ID -
>   File ID].

Again not a hard task, you can use the following:

```
command > "${RecordingDate} - ${RecordingUnitID} - ${FileID}"
```

but not recommening this. Sure will be better name the files **without** spaces, for example:

```
command > "${RecordingDate}-${RecordingUnitID}-${FileID}"
```

if you want rename the file use the `mv` command, like:

```
mv oldfilename.ext "${RecordingDate}-${RecordingUnitID}-${FileID}.$newext"
```

Ps: if you want some more precise answer, try ask more precise. :)

Comment: +1: Nice answer. Especially the creation of new directories part.

Comment: edit your question and show the code what cause the problem. If is impossible give a good advice only based on textual question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying `mv` more files into "one file".

```
mv $FLACS/*.flac $FLACS/${RD}-${RU}-${FID}.$flac
```

`*.flac` is expanded to more files. You cant move more files into one. When moving more files, the mv want as his last argument a directory.

You probably want:

```
mv $FLACS/some_one_file.flac  $FLACS/${RD}-${RU}-${FID}.flac
```

Comment: So, how to make it rename the files sequentially based on user input. the important bit here is the File-ID. Audio-001.flac has to be renamed to 2552011-Unit05-001.flac. I'm only adding date and unit ID to the original file name.